# How to skip bind properties per profile in spring boot(@ConfigurationProperties, @ConstructorBinding)

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I want to optionally bind a field to specific class for each profile

the example code is as follows ...

```
spring:
  config:
    activate:
      on-profile: test1

app:
  cash:
    conn:
      connection-timeout: 1000
      response-timeout: 2000
...

---
spring:
  config:
    activate:
      on-profile: test2
```

```java
@Getter
@Validated
@ConstructorBinding
@ConfigurationProperties(value = "app.cash.conn")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class CashBoxConnectionProperties {

    @NotNull
    @Positive
    private final Integer connectionTimeout;

    @NotNull
    @Positive
    private final Integer responseTimeout;

    @NotNull
    @PositiveOrZero
    private final Integer retryMaxAttempts;

    @NotNull
    @Positive
    private final Integer retryMaxDelay;

}
```

When running as `test1` profile, the application runs normally because the properties value is set, but when running as `test2` profile, the error 'Binding to target...' occurs because there is no `app.cash.conn` properties.

The `CashBoxConnectionProperties` is not required in `test2` profile, so is there any other way than to remove `@NotNull` annotation?

Answer (score 0):

You can annotate the `CashBoxConnectionProperties` class with `@Profile("test2")`, which makes it only available when the `test2` profile is active. To make it work, the class should be marked as `@Component`, since `@Profile` is only applicable to Spring beans.

For more details check [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Profile.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can use validation groups, to turn off validation for specific fields.

I never used this myself, but you can find an explanation here: https://www.baeldung.com/javax-validation-groups